# My question is removed

Tags: discussion, support, specific-question, deleted-questions

Recently [my question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/336461/non-existence-of-a-parametrically-compatible-metric-to-a-complete-geodesible-vec) entitled "Non existence of a parametrically compatible metric to a complete geodesible vector field on $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus\{p,q\}$" is removed. What is the reason?

Comment: As Gerry Myerson correctly says, your question has been removed / autodeleted by the "Community" user. For autodeletion criteria, see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/enable-automatic-deletion-of-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year/92006#92006). For now, I have undeleted your question -- but if it doesn't get answers or upvotes, it will soon be autodeleted by the software again.

Comment: Maybe you might consider to offer a bounty - even if it does not bring some answers, it might at least bring more views and possibly some upvotes, if MO users consider the question interesting. Thus preventing this particular question from [roomba](https://mathoverflow.net/help/roomba).

Answer (score 5):

The question was posted in July 2019, and had no answers and no comments. It had one upvote, and one downvote. It was removed by the "Community" user as an abandoned question. Here's a link: [Non existence of a parametrically compatible metric to a complete geodesible vector field on $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus\{p,q\}$](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/336461/non-existence-of-a-parametrically-compatible-metric-to-a-complete-geodesible-vec)

Comment: I will add a link [to the help center](https://mathoverflow.net/help/roomba) which contains basics about roomba (auto-deletion). If somebody wants to see more details, some pointers are given [in the corresponding tag-info on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/auto-delete/info). (One of those links has already been mentioned in Stefan Kohl's comment.)